# One page per record

Tags: microsoft-access

I am trying to print each report on just a single page but have no idea as to how should I proceed. Let me explain:-

[image]

As seen from the report, Allan and Danny is now appearing in a single page but my requirement is only for one individual to appear in a page (i.e. Allan in 1 page and Danny in the other).

I am attaching the Design page for your vieiwing.

[image]

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: +1 for clear question. However, you may need to show your actual query (the SQL would be great). I would imagine you're missing a where clause (eg, where personName = 'xxxxx')

Answer (score 2):

1. Go into the properties of your `Name Footer`.
2. Navigate to the `Format tab`.
3. Find the option called `Force New Page`.
4. Change the value from `None` to `After Section`.

Comment: Hi! Daniel, thank you very much for your help. It works. May I know how do I set the header to appear on every page?

Comment: The report header only shows once on the first page.  The page header will show on every page.  The same analysis can be done with the footers.